# How can I center my logo on smartphone and tablet only?

Tags: css, wordpress, center, text-align

I have created my portfolio for graphic design on the url [sebastianpettersson.se](https://sebastianpettersson.se). The theme I’m using is called Lekker by Code Interactive. I have searched their support forum but sadly not found any solution to this issue.

My issue is:
I would like to have my logo horizontally centered when my visitors is viewing my page on smartphone or tablet. I’m somewhat a semi novice when it comes to css but tried using this code for it but it sadly does not work.

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 993px ) {
    .qodef-header-logo-link
        text-align: center !important!;
    }
}
```

(Note that I’m also using a code to hide a button on smartphone and tablet but I’m pretty sure it’s not interfering with it). Posting it to incase that is causing an issue.

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 993px ) {
    .qodef-m-lines{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You should also post the HTML, which the CSS is supposed to affect. Looking at your website, the `.qodef-header-logo-link` is an anchor element without any text in it. What you want to center is the anchor element itself and not its content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set width100% and margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 993px ) {
.qodef-mobile-header--minimal #qodef-page-mobile-header-inner .qodef-mobile-header-logo-link {
       margin-right: auto;
       margin-left: auto;
       width: 100%;
       max-width: 100%;
       min-width: 100%;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can center your logo by setting `margin-left` to `auto`, as it already uses `margin-right: auto`:

```css
@media only screen and ( max-width: 993px ) {
    .qodef-header-logo-link
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to be clear that **`!important!`** doesn't work you should use **`!important`** with only one!

Second, you can use `margin: 0 auto;` to center images,

Third, use flexbox:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Tip, try using

- `@media only screen and (min-width: 450px)` for small devices {}
- `@media only screen and (min-width: 800px)` for bigger devices {}
- `@media only screen and (min-width:1100px)` for even bigger devices {}

Answer (score 0):

@Robo Robok 's solution is the way to go. You could also try learning more about positioning and layouts by experimenting with `display: flex`.

The following change to your header will also work, if you want to alter the position of your collapsible menu too:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 993px) {
    #qodef-page-mobile-header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}
```

Also, you should have a look at your collapsible menu not appearing below 994px of resolution.